# Convert Unix Timestamp UTC 0 to Readable Date/Time

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a unix timestamp that is saved at `UTC 0`. I need to convert it to `GMT -08:00 ( PST - America LA ).`

I need to take that timestamp of `1546329808471` and convert it into

`Date format - m/d/Y`

`Time Format h:i a`

I have

```
$time = new DateTime(date('h:i a', $pickup['timestamp']/1000)); // which returns the time in UTC 0.
$date = date('m/d/Y', $pickup['timestamp'] / 1000); // is the date in UTC 0.
```

returning

`01/01/2019` at `08:03 am` which is correct for UTC 0, but not PST.

Comment: You can use `date_default_timezone_set` function

Comment: can you give me an example in an answer.

Comment: Yes sure, You can see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `setTimezone()` and create an object of `DateTimeZone` class to achieve your result.

```
$pst = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$time = new DateTime(date('m/d/Y h:i a', $pickup['timestamp']/1000)); 
$time->setTimezone($pst);
print_r($time);
```

You can read more about it from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Comment: Getting a `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string ` when saving it to the database.

Comment: I got it, I was saving the object, and not the property.

Comment: have great day, Keep Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the default timezone first using **date_default_timezone_set** and then display the time/date as below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$time = new DateTime(date('h:i a', $pickup['timestamp']/1000)); 
$date = date('m/d/Y', $pickup['timestamp'] / 1000);
```